# Adsense: Both www.example.com and example.com are showing up in my Sites reports despite redirect

Tags: 301-redirect, google-adsense

I have a website `example.com` that was on `www.example.com` until around May 2015, when I moved it from Jekyll to WordPress. I have a 301 redirect set up from `www.example.com/*` to `example.com`.

Now, both domains are showing up in my Adsense Sites reports. The `www` variant doesn't have any page views, but it does show impressions, clicks, etc.

How can this be the case? And how can I fix this?

## example.com

[image]

## www.example.com

[image]

*red: impressions, blue: revenue*

Comment: How long ago did it used to be be on www?

Comment: Looks like it was on www until around May 2015. [I updated my question.]